# Web displays: Paging vs. long tables

Tags: html, pagination, html-table

It seems that the trend in web design is to provide paged output, where long tables are displayed a page at a time.  My customers don't like that, and have requested that the web sites I design for them show all entries in long tables.  The arguments for paging seem to be mostly based on the performance hit of displaying long tables, and this is less of a concern in a high-bandwidth corporate intranet.  Arguments against paging include the ability to print the entire table, do string searches against the entire table, select arbitrary ranges from the entire table for copying, etc.  I've pointed out that these features can easily be added to paged web designs (e.g. a print button that prints the entire table, or a button that creates a CSV file of the the table), but the paged output still seems inconvenient to them.  Our typical table is about 100 to 600 items.  Obviously tables that would be significantly larger would probably have to be paged.

**Questions:**

1. What is your experience with personal or customer preferences for paged vs. full output in long tables?
2. Web design tools seem to be pushing the paging paradigm.  Are they out of touch, or are my customers unusual?
3. If you're thinking "It depends on the length of the table", what threshold would you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I love long one-page listings.
   One of the few reasons I can see for paged
   listing is the ones you point out about performance.
2. I think your customers are very usual and in-touch.
3. The threshold would be about page loading times. When the server can't produce the full lists fast enough or when the lists gets so long that the browser slows down. (The latter can happen for quite short lists if you have non-a-tag hover stuff in your CSS and the browser is IE.)

Give the users a powerful search function and they'll narrow down their page lists themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply have it be a user configurable option. It sounds like you plan to essentially implement both anyway.

To be honest I think that no matter which you choose someone will complain. At least with it being user configurable you have the ability to put it back on the user.

Comment: You obviously is not a believer in Getting Real by Avoiding Preferences (http://gettingreal.37signals.com/ch06_Avoid_Preferences.php). But I am. I think making good choices for your users so that they don't have to is the best help you can give them.

Comment: I can understand the theory, but as a power user I hate the application when applied to me. :)  I suppose that the answer I provided is from a me as user viewpoint.

Comment: To address that post specifically, I think it will depend on the data. Specifically how long does it take to make the big list. As an example I always keep google set to 100 per page and I wish it were larger, but that is only practical because current internet speeds allow it to render quick enough

Comment: Well, when the developers make bad choices (like on the iPhone where they think auto-tilting the page when the device is tilted is a good idea) then it sucks. But when the choices are good ones then you just don't notice them.

Comment: From the post "Yes, you might make a bad call. But so what. If you do, people will complain and tell you about it. As always, you can adjust. Getting Real is all about being able to change on the fly."

Comment: the problem is that this is the sort of thing that no matter how you adjust there will still be complaints in this instance.

Comment: I doubt it. I know of no users who wants paging when they can have everything on one plate. Especially if you give them a search box that can narrow down the list to just the few items they're interested in.

Comment: Then why do you think paging is so prevalent? I have to think that if everyone all wanted it the same way, then the other way wouldn't be as popular.

Comment: And to keep with the google example, if I were still stuck on a 56k dial up (and don't kid yourself a lot of people are), then I certainly wouldn't be doing 100 per page. It is true that you could detect speed and adjust dynamically, but I think that would add unneeded complexity.

Comment: I want to be clear though that none of this discussion in any way *proves* that the user configuration is best. It is just me expressing my personal opinion.

Comment: I think you and I are in agreement. The only reason for paging I can accept is page loading time issues. I work on a system where IE forces us to do paging because of it's lame implementation of hover on non-a-tags. On an intranet, with beefy servers. Go full listings!

Answer (score 1):

Provide a default page length, and a configurable parameter (e.g. in the query string for programmatic use, and/or a form on the webpage for interactive use) to control how many listings are in a page.

User flexibility is good. Texas Instruments has a parametric search tool for electrical engineers to find ICs that meet certain technical characteristics, and they include a link both to "show all" in a webpage and "download all" as a .csv file. That's a good model, kudos to TI. Ditto to flickr; their API lets you control (to a large extent) how many results show up on a web service call.

I personally HATE websites that default to 10 listings per page with no way to increase it. It takes FOREVER to browse them, & I'm willing to wait longer if I can get all the stuff at once.

If it's an interactive webpage, I would consider going to an AJAX solution that downloads 100 at a time so there's an indication of progress (and the user can stop it if there are 20000 results).

I agree with PEZ, it's all about responsiveness.

Comment: Indeed, lately I've seen some sites that lets the user get more data on the same page by clicking "load more". It makes sense at times.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution: Don't provide lists with more than 100 items.

Usually your user doesn't want to read more than 100 or even 600 items. They just don't care. They are searching for one (or possibly a few). Make sure that there's a way for them to get to those items without [visual-grep-ing](http://www.jargondb.org/glossary/vgrep) through the list.

And if your client insists on displaying all items, then provide paging with a configurable page size and let him enter "100000 items per page" if he wants to.

Comment: I think I am the exception. As an example, I will do a google search for something then as I am looking at the hits I will notice a term that I think might be relevant. As a quick check I will use the browser search to look for the term. This works best with a really big list.

Comment: I'm another exception. I prefer huge list and a way for me to shorten it down via searching.

Comment: It's important to note that the mind of the average developer works a bit different in this respect than the average user. So it's often not a great idea to derive what the customers want from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One of the seminal books on web design (sorry, I forget which one) used to say not to count on your users scrolling down because most of them don't know how or can't be bothered.  I think a more recent update says that while is is true for the general public, certain sectors of more technical users can be expected to scroll down and you can make pages that require scrolling IFF (if and only iff) you know your users can handle it.

Comment: I think this has never been true.

Comment: Oh, it has been true (and still is), but you'll have to differentiate between a web site (that presents some information that the user might or might not be interested in) and a web application (where the user wants to get some stuff done). The latter requires a bigger degree of involvement.

Comment: Maybe if your application is for senior citizens it's true for a small percentage of them.

Comment: I think saua has it right - that advice was for sites where you're trying to bring people in, like a shopping site.  It's traditional newspapers that put the stuff that will grab a casual passer by on the front page above the fold.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your situation extremely well. I have been in similar situation. I moved a business workflow from being man managed to an automated one. Initially it was carried out using excel spreadsheets. The stakeholders for my software were in the age group of 55+ they dont like anything ajaxy or any of the UI patterns you are talking about. It such cases data retreival logic can be optimized. Any table that touches the 1K mark or has item like image blobs or things like that should be shown in parts from a performance point of view.

1. long outputs slow rendering and will be performance leech
2. Customers dont want to changes most times and customer is always right unless u can convince them.
3. I have put forth my threshhold but it also depends on the content of the rows.

Happy Coding!